# "Please look straight. Do not turn your body to the side."

Tags: expressions

I was proctoring an exam for a teacher, and I noticed that some students turned their body toward the next person. I felt like they might cheat. So, I wanted to tell them to look straight (take a straight posture) in proper english. Not sure if this is grammatically correct and not awkward to say to my fellow american students. "*Please look straight (or straight forward?). Do not turn your body to the side.*"

Thanks so much!

Comment: _Look straight ahead_ is the phrase you want. It means to focus your gaze to the front and not to look to the side. _Straight ahead_ is short for _straight ahead of you_, in this case.

Comment: What @bib said, plus you may want to add, "and sit correctly in your chair" because if they are sitting sideways, "facing forward" would have them facing the student at their side. :-)

Comment: You might be interested in [ell.se], a sister site to this one, designed to help the English learner.

Answer (score 9):

A common phrase used to seek students full attention and directing them toward the front of the room is

> Please face forward!